# Javaのクラスに関する質問です。 以下の書き方を教えてください。

Tags: java

以下の条件で、Calendarクラスを使用して、`yyyy/MM/dd`形式で誕生日を取得しなさい。

1. Calendarクラスの変数名 = calendar
2. 実行する日より「5ヶ月15日後」の日付を表示しなさい

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ここへ日付のフォーマットを記述");
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()) + "で" + this.getAge() + "歳になります！");
```

Comment: 他の質問もそうですが、「課題を解くにあたって何が分からないのか」をもう少し具体的に説明してみてください。今の書き方だと単に「代わりに課題を解いてください」といった印象を与えてしまいます。

Answer (score 1):

`this.getAge()`でエラーになるのでこちらを除外したコードになります。

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()) + "で" + "歳になります！");
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
    
    }
}

// 2022/10/16で歳になります！
// 2023/03/31
```